# How can i have a tab into a tabHost without a view in the tabWidget?

Tags: android, android-tabhost, tabwidget

I wanna hide 1 tab indicator View in a tabHost , cause i'll use another button to do it . The problem comes when i hide it this way:

```
 getTabHost().getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Then the separators still appearing in the tabWidget .

Any idea of how can i do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If i am getting you right , you want to change view of tabIndicator .
if so then use `setindicator(view)` at the time of adding tab .

for more help `tabs1.java` in ApiDemoes  .

Comment: setindicator(view) : Can view be getted from out of the tabWidget bar?